# Is there a way to animate/translate this div from bottom: 0 to top: 0 easily?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the below code to transition smoothly from bottom: 0 to top: 0. I understand that transitions only work with the same attribute, but I'm at a loss on how to do it smoothly right now. Here's the code in question:

```css
.portCard * {
  max-width: 100%;
  transition: .35s .35s transform cubic-bezier(.1,.72,.4,.97);
}

.portCard {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 250px;
}

.portCardContent {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0px);
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #86B971;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 0;
  height: auto;
}

.portCard:hover .portCardContent {
  top: 0;
  bottom: auto;
}

.portCardTitle {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.portCardText {
  font-size: .8em;
}

.portCardLink {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
                <div class="portCard">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1586511925558-a4c6376fe65f?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=687&q=60" alt="">
                    <div class="portCardContent">
                        <h3 class="portCardTitle">
                        Make your <span>choice</span> right now!
                        </h3>
                        <p class="portCardText">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia quisquam doloremque nostrum laboriosam, blanditiis libero corporis nulla a aut?</p>
                        <a href="#" class="portCardLink">
                            <span>Learn How</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine top (or bottom) with translate. In your case, use `bottom: 100%` which will make your item out of the container but you rectify this using `translatey(100%)`

```css
.portCard * {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.portCard {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 250px;
}
.portCard img {
  display: block;
}

.portCardContent {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #86B971;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: .5s;
}

.portCard:hover .portCardContent {
  translate: 0 100%;
  bottom: 100%;
}

.portCardTitle {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.portCardText {
  font-size: .8em;
}

.portCardLink {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="portCard">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1586511925558-a4c6376fe65f?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=687&q=60" alt="">
  <div class="portCardContent">
    <h3 class="portCardTitle">
      Make your <span>choice</span> right now!
    </h3>
    <p class="portCardText">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia quisquam doloremque nostrum laboriosam, blanditiis libero corporis nulla a aut?</p>
    <a href="#" class="portCardLink">
      <span>Learn How</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Appreciate it, that's what I get for working past 10pm lol. Thanks!